# How can I get one line and other lines in two parts in C?

Tags: c

I try to get input from a text file. First line of the text only contains a number, then others related with it like that;

```
4
ssss
sss
ss
s
```

I used fgets function for getting these lines from file, but I want to use "4" and the other lines in different functions.

I was getting both these lines with fgets like that;

```
    char inp[150];
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    while(1) {
      if(fgets(inp, 150, fp) == NULL) break;
      printf("%s",inp);
      i++;
    }
```

I used printf for only see that this code getting all lines or not. It is getting all lines same with input, but when I try to print first line of the input "inp[0]", I expect to print "4", but it prints "s" again.

Therefore, I can't use or get the number which is in the first line. How can I print or use first line independently from others.

By the way, the number and the other lines ,which are related with it, can change with another inputs.

Comment: Do you ever call `fopen`

Comment: Use `while (fgets(inp, sizeof(inp), fp) != NULL)` rather than an infinite loop.

Comment: Where (at what point in the while loop) do you print `inpu[0]`?

Comment: If you use `fscanf()` to read the number, that will leave the newline in the input buffer to be processed by the first `fgets()`.  Generally, it's easiest not to mix `fscanf()` with `fgets()`.  If you're using separate functions, then pass the file stream to each function (use `fopen()` and `fclose()` in a coordinating function, and pass the opened file stream to the other functions that read the file).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It will make it easier for people to advise you since we won't have to guess what your problem is.  You show sample input, but the code is fragmentary (not complete) and you don't clearly show the actual (or expected) output.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Unfortunatelly using dynamic data structures are not allowed for this code.

Comment: Who said anything about dynamic data structures?  You're using `fgets()` with a file stream `fp` — that's what you provided.  I didn't advocate using anything more dynamic than that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is from my homework, and they said "You are not allowed to use any dynamic data structures", Then I thought using sizeof()  may be a problem. Isn't it? But I tried fopen and fclose now

Comment: In this context, `sizeof()` is the antithesis of 'dynamic' because it produces a compile-time constant, which is as undynamic as it gets.

Comment: another possibility for avoiding infinite loop is explicitly checking against EOF `while(!feof(fp)){ …code for reading from file…}`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the file pointer to the functions, and have them attempt to read the lines.
That's a basic parser for you.

Don't forget to:

1. Do error handling, and properly indicate if a read failed.
2. Reset the file pointer position in case of failure.
   Store the result of `fgetpos` at the beginning and restore it with `fsetpos`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `fgets(inp, 150, fp)` reads until newline, 149 characters read or EOF. 
So each time`fgets(inp, 150, fp)` you store new values in `inp`. And last value is `s`.

Try to use `fgetc` and store character by character in `inp`.

Comment: This diagnosis could be the source of confusion.  I'm not sure that dropping down to use `fgetc()` is the best solution — though it can be made to work.

Comment: or you can use `buf[150]` to temporary store value, then each time `strcat(inp, buf)`. But first declare like this: `char inp[150] = "";`